# Where's an appropriate place to keep my nginx cache on Ubuntu?

Tags: nginx

Nginx specifies https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cache_path: `/data/nginx/cache` but that doesn't see like a normal place to store anything on ubuntu. [Another place](https://serversforhackers.com/nginx-caching) suggest `/tmp/nginx`.

What's an appropriate ubuntu-convention for my cache?

Answer (score 1):

Any place you like; `/var/nginx`, `/var/tmp/nginx`, `/data/nginx/cache`, `/home/ngin`x .. it really doesn't matter, as long as there are enough disk space at the location for the job.

I wouldn't put it in `/tmp`, since from the olden days, everything there can go away on a reboot.